# Python subprocess - Get into a pseudo terminal to run commands into remote ssh terminal as args or as inputstream

Tags: python, shell, ssh, inputstream, outputstream

I am doing ssh using the subprocess run command. I am aware of `popen` through https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-run-external-command-and-get-output/ - it works.

I am trying run command at the moment. I am getting an error when I use the run command: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal`.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = ["ssh", "-i", "sshkey.pem", "user@111.1.1.1"]
>>> ip = 'exit'.encode('utf-8')
>>> result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, input=ip)
>>> # I want to access the ssh terminal here and run a few commands like  ip in the ssh terminal
```

My basic goal is to:

- Run a few commands like `exit` (the `ip` variable) in the SSH terminal using code. Which arguments can be used for SSH terminal input and output in the SSH pseudo terminal, `IF` I can access one in `.run()` command. (I am looking at this [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output))
- Run a few commands like exit in the SSH terminal using shell with (a.) possibly be able to stream output of the SSH terminal and (b.) possibly be able to stream inputs into the SSH terminal.

## UPDATE:

Able to get into the shell using the `.popen()` function. Unable to run list of commands from code automatically even using `.communicate()` function even with `.popen()` using `input` argument, not just `.run()` function.

```
cmd = ["ssh", "-i", "sshkey.pem", "user@111.1.1.1"]

r = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, input=ip)
# does not work with ip
# Unable to run list of commands into the process automatically via commands

c = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
# Unable to run list of commands into the process automatically via commands

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = p.communicate(input='exit'.encode())[0]
# Able to get into the shell of the subprocess
# but unable to run list of commands into the shell automatically, output doesnot work using `input` options
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: code work correctly if I use `bash` instead of `ssh` - so all problem makes `ssh`. It may have problem to access `stdin`.

Comment: @furas Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Comment: @furas yes, even I was expecting that. what should be the stdin - subprocess.PIPE? It did not work for both showing the shell while running the run() function nor getting a shell allocated through code (that will get a set of commands in a list or bash script running)

Comment: I don't know what it should be - I use module [fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/) (which uses module [paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/)) to run `ssh` - `result = fabric.Connection('pi@raspberry').run('ls', hide=True)` and `print( result.stdout )`.

Comment: for sending many commands in one session I would use [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html) with `ssh` or even [pxssh](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html)

Comment: @furas I have seen paramiko. It is `very` good. I dropped it to avoid an external dependency. Let me have a look at fabric. Is it possible for me to use it without an external dep? Let me have a look at the code and see if I can replicate it in a simpler way in my code. I am intending to use `run` or `popen` of which `popen` worked. But I am unable to stream stdin and stdout for both `popen` and `run`. I am trying to find the args options to allow that and access that to the `result`ing object in my case

Comment: @furas updated the commands for `popen` and `run` in the code above. Unable to run list of command codes automatically using code from both popen and run.

Comment: farbric use paramiko. You think that with `popen` it  will be `simpler way` but it will not.

Comment: @furas true. It is not about `ssh` actually. If I use a different command with `popen` how do I add inputs to stdin programmatically with `run` or with `popen`?

Comment: @furas say I run a telnet command, what options do I use to write to shell programmatically in `run` of subprocess or `popen` of subprocess